# Default RelayState for Google for Work SAML App

Tags: google-apps, saml

I am trying to configure BIME Analytics as a service provider (SP) to use Google for Work as a SAML Identity Provider (IdP).

Following the instructions at https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en I am able to perform SP initiated authentication. This means if I visit https://.bime.io/portal and click the SAML login button, I am redirected to a Google login page and after entering my Google for Work credentials am able to access my BIME portal page.

Unfortunately, I cannot get IdP initiated authentication to work. That is, from Gmail for example, if I open the app launcher and click on the icon for my BIME SAML app, it will take me into BIME without any authentication issues, but then I get a BIME dashboard not found error.

BIME support was able to identify that this is because I was not sending a RelayState parameter value which they require. When I start in BIME, I'm on their webpage and there is a hidden RelayState value that is sent to Google to let it know where to send me after I log in. However, when I start in Google, that value is not set. BIME support was able to configure the connection in Okta because Okta has a "Default RelayState" field that they could hardcode a value into.

For Google SAML apps, how do I specify a default RelayState value to enable IdP initiated authentication into a SAML app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yesterday I took a look at the IdP SAML setup page in G Suite and noticed there is an optional "Start URL" field.

I also noticed in the [help documentation to configure pre-integrated SAML applications](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6194926#fdsp) that the "Start URL" field was frequently used.

Since the configurable parts of an IdP response are:

- SAMLResponse With Assertion (including "Assertion Consumer Service URL" and "Entity ID" fields in G Suite config page)
- RelayState parameter

I had to guess that the "Start URL" is likely the field to hold the RelayState parameter. Considering RelayState is an optional--but important and commonly used--part of the SAML integration this makes a lot of sense. It also explains why the field is optional, and directly below the ACS and Entity ID fields.

[This Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/dcarru/entry/integrating_google_idp_with_oif) references the Start URL field and suggests one of its uses is to contain the unsolicited RelayState value:

> Optionally enter a Start URL for Google IdP Initiated SSO operations,
>   where the user will click on the SAML Application partner at Google to
>   be redirected to the Application at OAM: this would be the protected
>   application URL, or unsolicited Relay State.

So while I can't test myself at the moment, I think it's safe to say this "Start URL" field is what you're looking for to set your RelayState value.

Comment: I just verified this. Just put the value of the desired RelayState parameter into the Start URL field.

Answer (score 1):

The relaystate URL you are looking for is

> https://www.google.com/a/[DOMAIN]/ServiceLogin?continue=https://mail.google.com

More info [here](http://saml-doc.okta.com/SAML_Docs/How-to-Enable-SAML-2.0-in-Google-Apps.html)